# How can I change environment variables using guard with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, guard

I'm using RSpec and Guard to test my rails app.

It's all working well, but I have some tags that are ignored if there's no environment variable set.

For example:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

  config.treat_symbols_as_metadata_keys_with_true_values = true
  config.filter_run focus: true
  config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true

  config.filter_run_excluding :slow unless ENV["SLOW_SPECS"]
end
```

So specs marked as `:slow` will only be run when SLOW_SPECS=1 in my environment

How can I change this value without having to restart guard?

Comment: `ENV["SLOW_SPECS"] = nil` in run time should work, if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: Thanks @Dolphin. I'm looking to change that environment variable in Gaurd though - since I don't believe the changes will be carried across multiple terminal windows and I don't want to have to quit guard whenever I'm changing filters

Comment: I'd love to know this too.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you're using `guard-rspec` to run your specs, you can pass in any environmental variable using the `cmd` option, for example:

```
guard :rspec, cmd: 'SLOW_SPECS=false spring rspec' ...
```

and updating your RSpec configuration to include:

```
config.filter_run_excluding :slow unless ENV["SLOW_SPECS"] == "1"
```

Comment: This answer requires restarting guard. The OP requested a solution that doesn't need that.